# Стили андроид

Tags: xml, android, java, css

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста одну вещь насчет стилей. Допустим у меня есть стиль для кнопки в котором я описываю как она выглядит (цвет фона, цвет и размер шрифта, толщина и цвет бордера и тд). Я применяю этот стиль к нескольким кнопкам. Вроде все здорово. 
Но вот как быть с позиционированием кнопки? Например я хочу чтобы кнопка была в левом верхнем углу своего родительского контейнера. "Ну так добавь это условие стиль своей кнопки" скажете мне вы. Но проблема в том что к другой кнопке я тоже хочу применить тот же стиль но разместить ее например в правом нижнем углу контейнера. Я кноечно знаю что можно наследовать стили но это немного не то что хотелось бы. Поэтому вопрос. А можно ли применять к кнопке несколько разных стилей? Чтобы не плодить наследуемые стили а просто сделать несколько базовых и комбинировать их в любой комбинации (наприменр отдельные стили для внешнего вида и отдельный стиль для позиционирования)? То есть так как это есть в веб разработке где к элементу можно применить несколько разных классов и навешивать на каждый класс свой стиль

Comment: нельзя применять к кнопке несколько разных стилей

Comment: а как быть7

Comment: @JuniorTwo, наследовать стили. Только так.

Comment: Не стоит определять расположение элементов в стилях. Для этого придумали разные Layout'ы.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению такое реализовать не получится (по крайней мере я не нашел решения). При этом наследовать стиль можно только от одного предка, применить к элементу не более одно, и самое страшное что из кода вообще нельзя установить стиль (опять же из моего опыта).

А для разделения стиля внешнего вида и расположения элемента могу вам посоветовать в стилях описывать только внешний вид а позиционирование определять в каждом элементе отдельно.